Cannot create a new WinUI 3 app and target .NET 8
X-Post from Github, please see linked thread:
https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/9539
Describe the bug
After creating a new WinUI 3 project using the project template, the framework version and nuget references are not current. In this state, targeting .NET 6, the app builds and runs, and you can see the clicky button screen.
The first order of business after executing any project template is to update to the latest framework and packages. With .NET 8, there are documented RID issues that are extern from this SDK. I found a workaround (UseRidGraph) on Stack Overflow to opt out of RID graph pruning, which lets the build pass.
Updating the nuget packages prior to targeting .NET 8 does not change the scenario. The error is introduced when retargeting to .NET 8, not when updating the nuget packages to current.
Build is passing with these props:
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
  <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
  <RootNamespace>Company.Product.Frontend.WinUI</RootNamespace>
  <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
  <Platforms>x86;x64;ARM64;</Platforms>
  <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x86;win-x64;win-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  <PublishProfile>win10-$(Platform).pubxml</PublishProfile>
  <UseRidGraph>true</UseRidGraph>
  <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
  <EnableMsixTooling>true</EnableMsixTooling>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>

However, when you start the app, you get this error:
Application: Company.Product.Frontend.WinUI.exe
CoreCLR Version: 8.0.424.16909
.NET Version: 8.0.4
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)
   at Company.Product.Frontend.WinUI.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\me\source\repos\Company.Product\Company.Product.Frontend.WinUI\obj\x64\Release\net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win-x64\App.g.i.cs:line 28

Steps to reproduce the bug
Install the SDK and create a new project as documented: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/create-your-first-winui3-app
Upgrade nuget packages to latest version, update target framework to latest version, opt out of RID graph pruning.
Run the application and see the application event log for crash details.
✅ running out of the box on .NET 6 and outdated SDK
✅ running after updating nuget SDK versions
✅ build for .NET 8 only passed after applying the UseRidGraph workaround:
❌ running after retargeting to .NET 8
Note: UseRidGraph workaround was applied; this seems to be a separate issue.
After updating to .net8, reference the System.Windows.Controls in the xaml editor

Weird. Can't reproduce this on my side. Can you make sure you have .NET 8 installed?

.NET 8 is for sure installed.

dotnet sdk check |

Microsoft.AspNetCore.App          8.0.4        Up to date. |
Microsoft.NETCore.App             8.0.4        Up to date. |
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App      8.0.4        Up to date. [see also error message that lists the SDK version]

Try add true in your csproj

I can't reproduce. Looks like the WinAppSDK runtime is not not installed. For information, my Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll is located in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.5_5001.95.533.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe. You can use Procmon to check where your app is failing to find it from (filter by file access and your process name) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll' may be resolved with a system reboot.
It seems that a system reboot was required after installing the tooling.  After rebooting I am getting the similar "working just fine" behavior as noted in other comments.
